# RegExp from string: replace "greater than" sign

Tags: javascript, regex

If I have a s tring that contains `>` sign, how do I replace it using regular expression, that is contructed from string using `new RegExp()`?

```
var s = "\\>:\\)"; // this is definetely wrong string for regexp contructor
var reg = new RegExp(s, "g");
alert(msg.replace(reg, "IT WORKS!!");
```

Replacing `:)` is not a problem, `new RegExp(":\\)","g")` works fine, but how to add `>` to regexp so that it will work?

[[PLAYGROUND AND DEMO]](http://jsfiddle.net/me06rf5s/)

Again, it **must** be done by specifying correct string to RegExp contructor.

Comment: This sounds like a school assignment. Why do you really have to do it using this pretty convoluted way?

Comment: @pranav, try your solution in playground, it fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `html()`. `html()` will encode the string and return

```
this is angry smile &gt;:) how it looks?
                    ^^^^
```

Use `text` instead of `html` or replace the encoded `&gt;` using regex `/&gt;:\)/g`.

Also there is not need of escaping the `>`.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/k8ky05xn/)

```js
var msg = $("pre").text();
var s = ">:\\)";
var reg = new RegExp(s, "g");

$("pre").html( msg.replace(reg, "IT WORKS!!") )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre>this is angry smile >:) how it looks?</pre>
```

Comment: thanks! excellent answer! I have replaced my string for constructor to include `&gt;`, and it works now fine.

Comment: @kaytrance Welcome! Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was not the RegExp, but the calls to html().

I have an updated jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/sx8bxmnw/ that works.

```
var msg = $("pre").text();
var s = ">:\\)";
var reg = new RegExp(s, "g");
$("pre").text( msg.replace(reg, "IT WORKS!!") )
```

To answer your original question, Pranav C Balan was right in his comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
var msg = $("pre").html();

var s = "\\&gt;:\\)";
var reg = new RegExp(s);

$("pre").html( msg.replace(reg, "IT WORKS!!") )
```

updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/me06rf5s/)